# Access image in qresource file from QML

Tags: python, qml, pyside2, qresource

I'm attempting to port my C++ Qt application to use PySide2.  Within my QML I have the following:

```
# test.qml
Image {
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.leftMargin: 5
    Layout.rightMargin: 5
    source: "qrc:/resources/images/logo.svg" # <-- Problematic line
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    asynchronous: true
}
```

My `logo.svg` file is referenced inside of my `resources.qrc` file like so:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>resources/images/logo.svg</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

`main.py` looks like:

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl

import qml_rc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load("qrc:/qml/main.qml")

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`qml.qrc` looks like:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>qml/main.qml</file>
        <file>qml/test.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I compile my resources QRC file by running: `$ pipenv run pyside2-rcc -o src/ui/resources_rc.py src/ui/resources.qrc`.

Then I compile my QML QRC file by running: `pipenv run pyside2-rcc -o src/ui/qml_rc.py src/ui/qml.qrc`

Then I run my program using the following command: `pipenv run python src/ui/main.py`

The UI will popup, but with some errors in the console, notably:

`qrc:/qml/test.qml:25:9: QML Image: Cannot open: qrc:/resources/images/logo.svg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way that you import qml_rc you also have to do with resources_rc:

```py
import qml_rc
import resources_rc
```

**Note:** The names of the files that are used as components must be capitalized as indicated by [rule M16](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-checking-code-syntax.html), I suppose that test.qml is just a name used for the example, in my test I used Test.qml.

Comment: Ah, I had imported `qml_rc` but not `resources_rc` because I don't _directly_ reference anything in `resources_rc` from my Python code.  Everything in `resources_rc` is referenced from my QML code.  That was my confusion.  Fixed!

Comment: @roundtheworld Unlike C ++ where QFile looks for the resource in the executable, python does what it was imported because if you check the *_rc.py you will see that there is reference to the data.

Comment: And yes `test.qml` was just for my example, in my real code, the filename is cased correctly.